# How to customize the type of a User Attribute in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have created a set of new User Attributes and used them in my new User flow (Policy) in Azure AD B2C.

These attributes are of data type "Boolean" but when I run the user flow I get a textbox input instead of a checkbox.

Usually, I get the possibility to change it on the portal but now I can not find where to do so now.

Have anything changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the custom user attribute is added, go to **page layout**. In my case the attribute to add is on the **local account registration page**, you select where you have added it or want to add it.
Below you will have appeared the user attributes that that part of the flow has (yours should appear). From there you change the type of ticket, you can also change if it is optional or mandatory ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Azure AD B2C** > **User flows (policies)** > *Your user flow* > **Page layouts**.

The **User attributes** section of the **Page layouts** page allows you to change the user input type.

Comment: Actually, that's what I usually do but now I do not have any User Attributes sectionb on the Page layouts page